# Delphi Delete all records from FDTable

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, firedac

Iam trying to delete all records in my FDTable component using ,

`mytable.Delete;`

but no record is getting deleted.

can any one suggest me a way to delete all records in a FdTable.

**EDIT**

i modified it in this way,

```
  for i := mytable.RecordCount - 1 downto 0 do
  begin
    mytable.Delete;
  end;
  mytable.Refresh;
```

but it is taking lot of time because there a lot rows in my fdtable.

Comment: what is the underlying database ? -+ how many rows?

Comment: While @MartynA has given you the proper answer, it's worth noting that you should **never** use RecordCount the way you're using it, because it forces a read of every row in the table to calculate. Instead, use `while not MyTable.IsEmpty`. Your next step is to learn how to find the documentation, which describes both `EmptyDataSet` and `IsEmpty`.

Comment: @user763539, My underlying DB is Oracle 11g.

Comment: For betther performance you can try delete all records using SQL.
Use a SQL component and a query like this: "DELETE FROM Table". Using SQL, the server (oracle) do the work instead the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove all the records in the underlying database table (the best way to do that will depend on the database) and call refresh just once.

If you must do it via TFdTable, use BeginBatch, do your deletes (without refresh), EndBatch and only then Refresh.

```
 mytable.BeginBatch;
 for i := mytable.RecordCount - 1 downto 0 do
 begin
    mytable.Delete;
 end;
 mytable.EndBatch;
 mytable.Refresh;
```

Comment: If no of rows in a table increases, it will be performance issue again.
it is taking lot of time to delete current 600 rows. If it increases morethan 1000 or something else, the application gets hanged.

Comment: Then take first approach. Clear data from the database directly without reference to myTable and refresh myTable afterwards. Use something like the SQL statement 'DELETE FROM *TableName*'

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
MyTable.EmptyDataSet;
```

There may be a bit more to do than that, but you don't say how you are populating `MyTable` in the first place.

Comment: I had Connected MyTable to a table in DB, MyTable will get data from DB directly, and then iam posting the same data in myTable to ClientDataSet, and then i have to empty all the data in the mytable.

As you said i also tried the `myTable.EmptyDataset`  but, It is deleting only one row , it only works if i use it in the for loop.

Comment: Do you actually want to delete the records from the DB, or just remove them from your MyTable but leave them in the DB?

Comment: Those should be deleted in DB also.

Comment: What type is DB and do you use SQL to retrieve the records?

Comment: If you want the data to be also deleted in the DB, then your best solution would be to run sql statement (Delete From tablename) and let the database layer do all the work, I dont see how myTable (FDTable) will also delete data in the DB at once

Comment: @MartynA , In the old code with BDE we used paradox tables created a Paradox Table and added data from Main DB(Oracle) table, and Clear the Main DB(Oracle) table and again Posting the data from Paradox Tbl to Table in Main Database(Oracle),No we replaced the BDE with FireDac and paradox with ClinentDataset.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a stored procedure for the job and not SQL from your application. Stored procedures are simple to make and blazing fast because they operate directly on the server.
Just create a stored procedure for your table;

> sp_deleteall

and do in it a single line of sql:

> delete from mytable

From your application,drop a TFDStoredProc on the form, link it to your stored procedure on the server and just call on the procedure
`

> sp_deleteall.ExecProc;

To know how many records were deleted just call, after the procedure execution :

```
ShowMessage(IntToStr(sp_deleteall.RowsAffected) + ' records were deleted.');
```

Try it ...

Answer (score 1):

Form fastest to slowest. First two are commands you execute server side.

1. Close the table and do a SQL DDL command `TRUNCATE TABLENAME;` and then reopen. This requires exclusive access to the table.
2. Use a SQL DML command `DELETE FROM TABLENAME;`. This does not require exclusive access.
3. Use a loop client side. A lot slower and triggers a lot of events client side.

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do for delete all records on a FDMemTable is

```
MyTable.Active := False;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

as doing delete for all the rows would hamper the performance.

If that does not work then why don you create the dataset runtime and then free the object.

Comment: Really? You just close the table and open it , nothing else.

Comment: @mano Why did you delete the code from your answer? Now it doesn't seem to make sense.